# Appveyor - Cannot find module 'canvas'

Tags: node.js, npm, appveyor

My dev machines (Ubuntu & Windows) do build and test https://github.com/Codeuctivity/PdfjsSharp without any problem, but [Appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/stesee/pdfjssharp/builds/34800743/job/qwqkbwde5mrbw98d) complains while testing that there is a dependency missing:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'canvas'
```

The build [logs](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/stesee/pdfjssharp/builds/34800743/job/qwqkbwde5mrbw98d) a succesfull install of canvas:

```
> canvas@2.6.1 install C:\projects\pdfjssharp\PdfjsSharp\node_modules\canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
  
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
[canvas] Success: "C:\projects\pdfjssharp\PdfjsSharp\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node" is installed via remote
added 100 packages from 50 contributors and audited 100 packages in 6.246s
  
18 packages are looking for funding
```

What do I miss here? Seems like there is some appveyor specific issue here, isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched over to [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/github/Codeuctivity/PdfjsSharp) using that .travis.yml

```
language: csharp
mono: none
dotnet: 3.1.401
script:
  - dotnet restore
  - dotnet build -c Release
after_success:
  - dotnet test
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: dotnet nuget push ./PdfjsSharp/bin/Release/PdfjsSharp.*.*nupkg  -k $NUGET_API -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  on:
branch: master
```